# Sort input from the user into a list of lists in order to create proper parameters

Tags: python, input, bubble-sort

My code needs to get multiple inputs from the user and sort that input into a sorted list. I have the method of input-collection sorted. I just don't know how I can sort it into a list of lists.
This is my input collector.

```
names = []
while 1:
    b = input("Name->")
    if(len(b)>0):
        names.append(b)
    else:
        break

scores = []
while 1:

    b = input("Score->")
    if(len(b)>0):
        scores.append(b)
    else:
        break
```

I need it to sort into this format.

```
sortedList = [["Name", Score], ["Name", Score], ["Name", Score]]
```

I should point out that I'm in a high school computer programming class, which is why I don't know how to do this yet.

Comment: Have you tried searching for an answer [there are a lot on SO]? Also python docs, for example see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted or maybe you are looking for [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)?

Comment: As a side note: we don't put parentheses around the condition in `if` clauses, and `if len(b) > 0:` can be simply written `if b:`, as strings (and lists, tuples, dicts, ...) are considered False in boolean context when empty.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the inputs are the same length, you need to do this to make the list you want:

```
sortedList = []

for i in range(len(names)):
    sortedList.append([names[i], scores[i]])
```

You make an empty list, then loop through all the indexes of `names` and `scores` and add the corresponding values to the list.

Before doing this, you may want to check that the lengths of the two arrays are equal:

```
if len(names) != len(scores):
    print("The lengths are different!")
    exit(1)
```

Comment: 1. What if the values are different length, like the names?
2. I tried it and got this error:
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CAYDEN\Downloads\bowling scores.py", line 30, in <module>
    for i in range(names):
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in the previous answer — it's now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It's be working. Try it.

```
names = []
while 1:
    b = input("Name->")
    if(len(b)>0):
        names.append(b)
    else:
        break

scores = []
while 1:

    b = input("Score->")
    if(len(b)>0):
        scores.append(b)
    else:
        break

sortedList = []
for i in range(len(names)):
    sortedList.append([names[i], scores[i]])

print(sorted(sortedList))
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can check with a tick that you have the correct answer. Thanks